# FlowChart: production management handle remainder of disassembled item

Tags: workflow, inventory, erp, flowchart

This is general question about the EPR/Inventory management that with production of:

1) assemble
2) disassemble

normally on assemble, the Finished Good that we produced will just go to inventory as stock. example:

Finished good:

```
1x Desktop CPU
```

Raw Meterials:

```
1x1TB HDD
2x2GB DDR3 RAM
1xMotherBoard
1xIntel Core i7
1xPower Supply
1xAtx Casing
```

On reversal production, we will disassemble the finished goods, and get the raw materials and put back to inventory as stock.

**Problem is:** when i have **1000ml** of fluid medicine as my raw material, and i disassemble it to **2x360ml**, and there is a remainder of **280ml**. How do i handle the 280ml of the fluid? we cant just trash the remainder, and also cant store the 280ml, because if we do this like 100 times, there will be 280mlx100 ended at no where?

I need some suggestion or opinion on how to handle this. I'm on the stage of developing flow chart. No programing related.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally sure that I understand your question, but let me try. If the assembled product could be stored, you could restrict the assembling process to use batches of 9 lts of raw material. In that way you create 25 x 360ml portion without any loss. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: that will make the system not flexible to handle thing, it will require user to take 9x1000ml to reverse the production.. why if there is only 3x1000ml on user end?

Comment: i mean only 3 at inventory

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a programming question. If you wish to disassemble your finished component, is this a reflection of the real world situation? If it is then presumably you should reflect this real world situation in your system. If it is not a reflection of reality, then presumably you can do whatever you deem sensible in the system to deal with any surplus.